# Swing dialog Paint Issue

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing GUI that displays a dialog when a trade occurs, but sometimes the pop-up does not paint.  Moving another application over the dialog paint area (place where the dialog should be displayed) causes the dialog to paint.  I haven't been able to re-produce the problem consistently.

I know that the "Direct3D Accelerated Rendering Pipeline" was enabled by default in version JDK 6u10, and that it is only compatible with certain video cards.

What is the best way to debug this issue?  Is there a way to verify that this is a problem with the new "Direct3D" setting?  How can i get more information to diagnose the problem.?

Comment: Is the popup displayed on the EDT?

Answer (score 4):

This could be one of a couple issues.  There is a chance that you are not painting in the Event Dispatch Thread, which could have undefined effects.  There is also a good chance that your program is throwing an exception while trying to paint.  Can you confirm that no exceptions are being thrown (or swallowed without being printed to the log/console)?